# Reapply *some* stickers on scrambled cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, twisty-puzzles, solvability

I have this weird cube which have some pieces printed on the plastic and some are detachable.
The cube was scrambled not solved and it fell on the floor being cheap cube almost all detachable faces fell off and I ended up with this *ugly monster*.

[image: scrambled cube with missing stickers]

[Here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/iPxdUsXzRnieaTSH8), More photos and a video of the cube state

This is the text version of the cube

```
    RGM
    RMO
    MOM
MMW RMR YMO BMB
OMW MMM RMM OMM
YMY MGO GMM WRM
    OMM
    RMB
    OMR
```

I replaced every missing piece with M.

In total I have 6 colors for the 6 centers and 5 pieces of each (White, Blue, Green and Yellow)

I thought this would be a fun little challenge for me to solve but I spent a lot of time configuring corners and edges and turns to be unsolvable scramble in the end.

Is this even possible to figure out and have the stickers back in logical way? I'm not like a cube master or anything to figure that out on my own.

Comment: Solve it without replacing the missing pieces, then add the missing pieces once you're done. For inspiration on how to solve it, you can have a look at [this problem I posed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89744/peeled-rubiks-cube) which seems very relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution, but some observations that may help get you there.

> All the moving pieces still have an orange or red facelet. Therefore red is opposite orange. If you place the four orange corners relative to each other, they only go one way and therefore determine the colour scheme and hence the corners colours, too. We can also put in the centres according to the colour scheme (it does not matter which orientation - there can be no parity problem due to the identical edges) and that results in the following:
>
> ```
>          R G w
>          R o O
>          g O g
>  y . W   R . R   Y . O   B . B
>  O b W   . w .   R g .   O y .
>  Y . Y   g G O   G . b   W R b
>          O . w
>          R r B
>          O . R
> ```

You can then try to solve it without putting any further colours in. It should be possible to do this, though I have not checked. A corners first solution method is very useful for this.

Comment: The result you posted has a missing the R center, is this intentional or you made a mistake while typing? I just want to make sure before changing the cube state.

Comment: @AhmedMohamedeen Good spot!. I accidentally typed it one line too high, putting it on the adjacent edge piece. Fixed it now.